# Simple local SIP server instead of asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, server

My aim is to set up a **local** SIP server so two android phones connected (via wifi) to this server can interact and call each other using SIP (imsDroid).

I've been messing with asterisk's server configuration during 4 days, with no luck. Followed hundreds of tutorials to configure asterisk (including official asterisk's quickstart) - always failed. I can't even connect to it using Zoiper on the same computer the server is running...

Asterisk seems too complicated to configure for my "simple" goal, so my question is:

**What is the most easy-to-configure local sip server ?**

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by local SIP server? What features do you need? Maybe Asterisk is not the best for your case...

Answer (score 1):

Most easy and documented is asterisk. All other more complex